# ggplot2 dodged boxplot with geom_point dodging and unequal number of subgroups

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, jitter, x-axis

I am attempting to plot a dodged boxplot but I run into a couple of difficulties. First of all, the x-axis basically has 2 types of grouping: the "letter-groups" (A, B, C etc...) are the main groups, I specify these as my "X" aesthetic (X_main_group). Within this main group I have subgroups called "X_group", the boxes are coloured by those subgroup types. What causes problems is that for each letter group I have different amounts of these subgroups, e.g. for x=A I have 4 subgroups but for x=B I have only one. This causes problems, for one the dodging of the plotted points do not work anymore (see the example plot below) as they do not align with the dodged boxplots. Secondly, the boxes are not centered around the x-axis tick anymore, this is most clear for x=B. How can I fix this?

I would also like to achieve small x-axis ticks below each subgroup (so 4 ticks for x=A, 1 tick for x=B, 3 for x=C etc..) but this has less priority. I have attached the figure, and in red I drew some examples of what I hope to achieve with the tick-marks. ggplot2 code is shown below. I would like to provide a reproducible piece of code, but I can not manage to create a piece of code that creates a dataframe with unequal amounts of subgroups so people that want to help can run it. I can only make "symmetrical" dataframes...

[image: example plot]

```
cbpallette <- c("#999999", "#666666", "#333333", "#000000", "#003300")
p1 <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=X_main_group,y=Intensity, colour=factor(X_group))) + stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width=.4, position = position_dodge(0.5, preserve="single")) + geom_boxplot(width=0.5, outlier.shape=NA, position=position_dodge(preserve = "single")) + theme_classic() + geom_point(position=position_jitterdodge(), alpha=0.3)
p2 <- p1 + scale_colour_manual(values = cbpallette) + theme(legend.position = "none") + theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(-0.1, "cm"), axis.text.x = element_text(size=30, vjust=-0.4), axis.text.y=element_text(size=35, hjust = 0.5, angle=45), axis.title = element_blank()) 
p3 <- p2 + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = .5, unit = "cm")), axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = .5, unit = "cm")))
p3
```

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I usually do this, but I don't know how to make a simple dataframe with an unequal number of subgroups in each main group... I am a novice, apologies.